# How do I generate a column of dates.

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

I want to generate a column of dates that are staggered by one month like this:

```
7/01/13
8/01/13
9/01/13
```

Right now what I've tried is dragging down the black dot in the lower right hand corner of the cell containing the first date, but then the day increments, which I guess makes sense.

I'm using open office. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Try selecting **two** cells containing consecutive dates and then drag the black dot. Autofill needs two values to determine the correct trend.